# Load dynamic data on click inside nested ngFor Angular

Tags: angular, nested, ngfor

I have a component that loads some items with id
and upon click of each item hit another Api by passing item-id that returns data based on the id Later i want to display this data right below the item i clicked
But unfortunately the data gets added under each item, how do i control this?

here's my code

```
//app.component.ts
  ngOnInit(){
     this.dataService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => this.posts = posts);        
  }
```

---

```
//app.component.html
<app-timeline [posts]="posts"></app-timeline>
```

---

```
//timeline.component.html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
       <button (click)="loadComments(post.id)">{{post.title}}</button>
          <ul class="comment-holder">
            <li *ngFor="let comment of comments">
                {{comment.body}}
            </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

```
//timeline.component.ts
 @Input() posts: any = [];
 comments: any = [];

 constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

loadComments(id){
  this.dataService.getComments(id).subscribe(comments => this.comments = comments);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You share the same 'commemts' array for all the rows. You have to think in another way to do it.

But, if 'id' of 'post' is a number and you want an easy change, maybe this could work:

```
//timeline.component.html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let post of posts">
       <button (click)="loadComments(post.id)">{{post.title}}</button>
          <ul class="comment-holder">
            <li *ngFor="let comment of comments[post.id]">
                {{comment.body}}
            </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

//timeline.component.ts
...
loadComments(id){
  this.dataService.getComments(id).subscribe(comments => this.comments[id] = comments);
}
....
```

Comment: a post can have multiple comments, and i want to display all of them not just one

Comment: With this solution, you would get ALL of the commentaries for every post (any post, all its comments). Have you tryed the code?

Comment: Works perfectly fine, i missed the loadComments() function initially..
Thanks Juan

Comment: You are welcome! I'm pleased it helped!